# Implementing Sorting query in Code: Utilizing the Sort Function for Enhanced Data Organization

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formData.DateFrom))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formData.DateTo))
    {
        // Both DateFrom and DateTo are provided
        mustQueries.Add(new DateRangeQuery(Infer.Field<PatientTimeline>(f => f.appointmentdate))
        {
            Gt = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.DateFrom, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal),
            Lt = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.DateTo, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal),
            TimeZone = "Z", // Adding TimeZone("Z")
            Boost = 1.0F,
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Only DateFrom is provided
        mustQueries.Add(new DateRangeQuery(Infer.Field<PatientTimeline>(f => f.appointmentdate))
        {
            Gt = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.DateFrom, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal),
            TimeZone = "Z", // Adding TimeZone("Z")
            Boost = 1.0F,
        });
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formData.DateTo))
{
    // Only DateTo is provided
    mustQueries.Add(new DateRangeQuery(Infer.Field<PatientTimeline>(f => f.appointmentdate))
    {
        Lt = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.DateTo, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal),
        TimeZone = "Z", // Adding TimeZone("Z")
        Boost = 1.0F,
    });
}
```

Hi guys :
This is my code and it is written in C# language and i am using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch library not Nest. this code is working but i want to add sort so that the data get display on  field "appointmentdate" in descending order. if anyone know about it kindly answer this question. Thank you

Comment: I think there should be a `Sort()` method that you can use with a lambda expression to specify if sorting should be done ascending or descending and what field should be used for sorting.

Comment: You can use OrderBy to do sorting.  Code posted is adding one line to query.  You want to sort after all the results are added.

Comment: There are various ways to do sorting in c#. You can sort in a database with IQueryable.OrderBy, In memory with different methods depending on collection type, or in a UI view with things like CollectionView. But it is not really clear to me what your code is doing. Or how you want to approach sorting.